# No HDMI out in Linux

Tags: linux, multiple-monitors, fedora, hdmi, pop-os

I don't get any output on my over HDMI connected monitor. While I do get output on my DVI monitor. I've tried Fedora 35 (Fedora-Workstation-Live-x86_64-35-1.2) as a live session and installed Pop!_OS (pop-os_22.04_amd64_intel_5) aswell as tried the live session. On Pop!_OS I've also got a few missing firmware messages but wasn't able to fix them by downloading the missing firmware from [kernel.org](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git), because it wasn't in the "amdgpu" folder.
My Monitor worked fine on Ubuntu 21.10 a few weeks back and works fine on Windows.
The most important specs are:

Sapphire RX 560

AMD Ryzen 2600

16gb DDR4 memory

How can I get my HDMI monitor to work? Help is appreciated

Edit: xrandr on Ubuntu 22.04 outputs following:

```
[...]
HDMI-A-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
[...]
```

Edit2: Missing firmware:

```
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/yellow_carp_gpu_info.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/vangogh_gpu_info.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/ip_discovery.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/cyan_skillfish_rlc.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/cyan_skillfish_mec2.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/cyan_skillfish_mec.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/cyan_skillfish_me.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/cyan_skillfish_pfp.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/cyan_skillfish_ce.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/cyan_skillfish_sdma1.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/cyan_skillfish_sdma.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/sienna_cichlid_mes.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/navi10_mes.bin for module amdgpu
```

Edit3:
My Monitor also doesn't work on Ubuntu 21.10 now

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Since Ubuntu is able to identify and download the needed HDMI driver, can you find it inj Ubuntu, and then use it (or find an equivalent) for the other OS's?

Comment: I will try that. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: Tried it and it didn't work. I've attached the xrandr output in the post

Comment: I'm guessing you'll have to edit some files in `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/`, specifically, `*device.conf`, `*monitor.conf` & `*screen.conf`. to tell the system what the primary device is.

Comment: Due to the directory being empty on Ubuntu 22.04 live and Pop!_OS I was unable to make any changes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix it by not having the HDMI cable connected until I logged in.

Answer (score 0):

I've installed the firmwares with `git clone git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git`. After that, copy the missing files to `/lib/firmware/amdgpu`.

Additionally, the open source driver amdgpu only works dual monitors when I've added the kernel parameter `amdgpu.dc=0` in GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT grub configuration file (/etc/default/grub).